# Possible null reference return warning in ConfigureServices()

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-6.0

Here is my code -

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                var cns = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db");
                services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseMySql(cns, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(cns)));

                //Possible null reference return warning here-
                services.AddScoped<IDatabaseContext>(provider => provider.GetService<DatabaseContext>());

                services.AddScoped<CensusService>();
            })
            .Build();
```

To remove that warning, what should be the right way to write the line?

Comment: What line is the warning on?

Comment: Why are you doing `services.AddScoped<IDatabaseContext>(provider => provider.GetService<DatabaseContext>());` instead of `services.AddScoped<IDatabaseContext,DatabaseContext>();` ?

Comment: @Dai services.AddScoped<IDatabaseContext> .....

Comment: @Dai- Your snippet works. Thanks. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: I believe you might also be able to simplify this by adding your Interface and your Context while you add it to your services : services.AddDbContext<IDatabaseContext, DatabaseContext>()

Comment: @Dai won't classes resolving `DatabaseContext` and `IDatabaseContext` get different instances with the suggested registration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) returns `T?` which will become nullable reference type if `T` is a reference type, while the registration requires a non-nullable one.

Use [`ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) which returns an instance or throws `InvalidOperationException` if there is no service of type `T`:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IDatabaseContext>(provider =>
    provider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>());
```

But in case of `DbContext` registration there are overloads of [`AddDbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions-adddbcontext-2(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-action((microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextoptionsbuilder))-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime)) allowing to split the contract and implementation (as suggested by Julien in the comments), so if you need to resolve context only via the interface you can use one of those:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<IDatabaseContext, DatabaseContext>(options => ...));
```

Related:

- [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)